# Convergence of first order subgradient methods for non-convex functions

Tags: optimization

This [lecture note](http://www.princeton.edu/%7Eyc5/ele522_optimization/lectures/subgradient_methods.pdf) gives the proof for how deterministic subgradient method converges on non-smooth convex and strongly convex Lipschitz functions.

Is there a non-convex version of this proof?

Like convergence of subgradient method for,

- non-smooth Lipschitz non-convex functions (like $\frac{1}{1+e^{-\vert x \vert}}$) ?
- non-smooth non-Lipschitz non-convex functions (like $(1-\vert x \vert)^2$)?

(happy to get references for the the stochastic versions of these too!)

Comment: On non-smooth optimization, better ask at Math SE, I would guess. There's a tag for it there.

Comment: Okay. If I dont get answers in a couple of days, I will move it there :D